# How do I post a checkbox array to a Spring 3 MVC controller?

Tags: post, spring-mvc, controller, forms

I have a html form which has a dynamic amount of checkboxes in it. How do I post these checkboxes as an array, and how do I recieve them in my spring 3 controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [tutorial](http://mattfleming.com/node/134) for a similar implementation. One of the key solution described in the blog is the use of [Apache Commons LazyList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/LazyList.html).